# Лишние запятые: "это различные характеристики, или свойства, элемента"

Tags: пунктуация

Так вышло, что я в последнее время стала замечать много ошибок в текстах (точнее, мне это кажется ошибками). Но одно дело, если это текст, опубликованный в интернете, а другое - вычитать в книге. Может, я не права, и это вовсе не ошибка.
Предложение такое:

```
Атрибуты - это различные характеристики, или свойства, элемента, которые можно...
```

имхо, "характеристики или свойства" - это один ряд и запятая ни к чему. Затем, подумав, предположила, что "или свойства" обособляется, т.к. это некое пояснение, хотя по смыслу это с натяжкой, но можно списать на авторскую пунктуацию.

Права ли я или здесь есть еще какое-то правило, корректор руководствовался другой логикой?..

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, в приведенном предложении выделение запятыми слов"или свойства"объясняется очень просто. У Розенталя есть правило об обособлении так называемых пояснительных оборотов, которые начинаются словами, "то есть, именно, или (в значении "то есть"), Так что "или свойства" - это как раз обособленный пояснительный член предложения.

Answer (score 2):

Без контекста очень трудно судить, насколько в данном случае "свойства" можно считать авторским уточнением для "характеристики". Но другого объяснения здесь не вижу. 
Для математика путать или смешивать свойства и характеристики - моветон, если только выше по тексту не указано, что вводится какое-то особое понимание этих терминов.

Ну а если это литература, скажем, по программированию, вполне можно предположить, что автор действительно так понимает и уточняет одно слово другим.

Касатально т.н. авторской пунктуации. Я думаю, что списывать на неё вообще ничего никогда не стоит. Авторская пунктуация для меня - это пунктуация не вопреки всем правилам, это когда автор использует необычную - но по правилам допустимую! - пунктуацию с целью облегчить восприятие, передать особенности речи, и т.п. Или просто в каких-то художественных целях - только последнее, собственно, и стоит называть авторской пунктуацией, В технических целях такая авторская пунктуация ни в узком, ни в широком смысле крайне маловероятна. За особенностью пунктуации должен стоять какой-то смысл - иначе это просто случайная ошибка.

Comment: Да, это книга по программированию

Comment: Тогда не сомневайтесь. Надо бы сразу скащать.